# Winform PictureBox inner picture size

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I've created a `PictureBox` and it's showing pictures in `zoom` mode.
I can easily access to the size of the pictureBox by calling

```
var size = pictureBox.Size;
```

But I can't figure out how to take the size of the inner picture i.e. the real on-screen size that the picture it's taking as the user is watching it

NOTE: I'm not looking for the size of the image

Comment: Do you mean: `PictureBox1.Image.Size;`?

Comment: PictureBox does not have a property that exposes the effective size, you [need this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,5c2ab37313f547c2).

Comment: @manuchao that's the real image size, not the displayed image Size.

Comment: @HansPassant that's what I've made by hand on my own, but i thought I could look for a canonical way. If you make it as an answer I'll pick it. Thx

Comment: Maybe you are looking for ClientSize? Which is Size - borders